# Netezza ODBC connection - equivalent of "use database"

Tags: netezza

After connecting to a Netezza system is there any way to switch the database?  For instance, in MSSQL one could send the command `use database_name` in order to switch to the database_name.

Is there anything in Netezza like "use" on mssql?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx

My reason for asking is in regards to metadata queries; I can only access _v_table of the "currently connected database".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prior to `Version 7.0` there wasn't an equivalent to `USE`.  You had to log in to specific databases on the server however you can still access any object using. `database.schema.objectname`

Post `Version 7.0` the equivalent is [`Set Catalog`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.0.3/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_set_catalog.html)

```
SET CATALOG <database_name>
```

Regarding your specific inquiry. Please consider using `_V_TABLE_XDB` instead of `_V_TABLE`.  This system table should provide you with a list of all tables, not just those in the database you are connected to.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using NPS v7.0+, then the SET CATALOG  command will connect you to a different database dynamically (without having to disconnect and reconnect). The beauty of this command is that it can be submitted from an ODBC/JDBC client as well as in an nzsql script.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: This should have been considered as the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Netezza you can to other database with following command -

```
nzsql -u <username> -pw <password> -db <databasename> -host <netezza server IP>
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As we know while executing any query in netezza we need to specify database name in connection url , which we should to make dynamic according to required database on which we have to perform operation, so in case of simple java code we can use the below Case 1) and in case of spring boot we can use below Case 2).

**Case 1)**
before executing any query in netezza we can execute statement as

**SET CATALOG #database name#;**

so it will automatically switch to database provided in set command.

**Case 2)**
We can switch the database in netezza with runtime switching of database

1. Use Apache basic data source (**BasicDataSource**) instead of **DriverManagerDataSource** while creating bean for datasource
2. Execute - **jdbcTemplate.execute("SET CATALOG #database name#")**
   Before executing any query.